# A variable of type Int cannot be assigned to an enum which is defined as Int

Tags: swift, enums, tags, int

Enum is declared at the beginning of the class.  Then I try to assign the TAG value to the enum; however the compiler is giving error saying: 'MenuItems is not convertible to Int'

What do you think is the problem here?

```
enum MenuItems : Int {
    case menuItemEmail = 0
    case menuItemName
    case menuItemPassword
    case menuItemAddPet
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: SettingsViewTableCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as SettingsViewTableCell
    cell.cellDescriptionText.tag = MenuItems.menuItemName
}
```

The last line is an error at compile time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enums with raw values have a `rawValue` property:

```
cell.cellDescriptionText.tag = MenuItems.menuItemName.rawValue
```

Comment: Now I know what the rawValue is for. Thank you!